# Releasing a branch on github with no history, allowing easy future merging

Tags: git, github

I have a private github project called PRIVATE with lots of history. I'd like to create a public github repo called PUBLIC that has a "release" of the project but with the following details:

1. It's public
2. It has no git history
3. It's possible to periodically merge changes from PRIVATE into PUBLIC

Given that I want PRIVATE to remain private on github, does that mean that PRIVATE and PUBLIC need to fundamentally be two separate github projects? Or is there some other way to do this? For example, can I make all of my existing branches on my project somehow private on github, but have my one new branch be visible and with no commit history?

Noting that I want to be able to pull changes from PRIVATE into PUBLIC every so often, what is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: If by "merges" you mean actual for-real merge commits, then there's no way to actually keep the private stuff private (I guess technically you could just not have anything referenced in private uploaded, but that's super-fragile and I suspect that Github won't participate in that ...). What you could do create an "upstream" branch in the public repo and periodically commit snapshots of whatever you want to make public there and then merge that.

Comment: Ok and just to double check -- is it the case that I should have two completely separate github repositories, one public and one private? Also: by commit snapshots, does that mean manually create a diff from the private repo and then apply the diff to the public repo's upstream branch (as you described)?

Comment: Is your purpose to hide your project commit history? Consider [cleaning up your history](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) instead.

Answer (score 2):

### What you need

I wouldn't recommend doing this because it's counter-intuitive for people coming onto the project; one false move and suddenly you've merged the two unrelated histories --> :-(

A project's commit history is as much a part of the project as the code itself. Once I got used to [browsing the commit history](https://jonas.github.io/tig/), I realized just how true this is.

Instead, I'd learn how to [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your commits to clean them up and organize them. Then it won't matter if you publish the entire history because it'll look still nice. Maybe those commits will even be something you're *proud of*.

### What you asked for

For this example:

- You've set up a `main` branch on `private`. This is going to contain the development history.
- There's a branch called `releases` on `public`. This is going to contain the "squashed" history i.e. one commit per release.

```bash
git remote add private <url1>
git remote add public <url2>
```

Then when you're ready to release:

```bash
# Add 1 commit onto "releases" that'll just update all files to how they look in "main"
# (This also includes any file additions or deletions in "main")
git fetch --all
git checkout releases && git pull
git checkout private/main .
git commit -m 'Release version 1.2.1'
# Publish the commit to the "public" remote
git push
# If there are tags associated, make and push them up to public: (*Note)
git tag v1.2.1
git push public v1.2.1
```

* You probably don't want to push these tags to `private` since they're going to be referencing orphaned commits.

Comment: Could you annotate your commands a bit more so folks can understand what's happening? 1) It's not obvious where the squash is happening 2) `git checkout releases && git pull` requires knowing shell fairly well. 3) Where did the local releases branch come from?